# Flowplayer RTMP Live Streaming on Amazon AWS (CloudFormation)

Tags: streaming, amazon-web-services, live, rtmp, flowplayer

I've followed [these instructions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingUsingAmazonCloudFront.html) in Amazon's AWS Documentation to forward a new domain name to Route 53 and then set up a CloudFormation stack with Flash Media Server at that domain.  I'm currently streaming a live video feed to my server, and have verified that it is accessible when I use the [OSMF Tester](http://www.osmf.org/configurator/fmp/).

Now I am trying to connect Flowplayer to this feed, but it won't load with any configuration I've tried.  Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $f("player","http://admin.lockwoodmediaroom.com/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",{
        clip:{
            url:'mp4:livestream?adbe-live-event=liveevent',
            live:true,
            provider:'rtmp'
        },
        plugins:{
            rtmp:{
                url:'http://admin.lockwoodmediaroom.com/swf/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
                netConnectionUrl:'rtmp://live-events.lmgondemand.com/livepkgr',
                subscribe:true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And in the body:

```
<a href="livestream?adbe-live-event=liveevent" id="player"></a>
```

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong here?  Any help would be very much appreciated, I've been stuck on this problem for 4 days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `clip` object try removing `mp4:` from the `url` property. I also had to remove the `subscribe` property in order for this to work for my stream.